# How to Fix: error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) rolling window wavelet correlation

Tags: r

i excute my code in R but this error message show when I use `plot_estim_RWWC()` function :

```
** Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
Warning message:
In par(oldpar) : calling par(new=TRUE) with no plot**
```

this my code that i use :

```
library(readxl)
library(RolWinWavCor)

X2=read_excel("Wavelet Coherence/02.xlsx")
sinX2 <- X2[-1]
sinX2 <- sinX2[c(1:8)]

lrX2 <- apply(log(sinX2), 2, diff)
tsX2<- ts(lrX2, start=1, freq=1)

Nnam <- dim(tsX2)[2]
lrX2 <- lrX2[,1:Nnam]
inputdata <- tsX2[,c(1,5)]
Wname <- "la8"
J <- 4
W <- 241
Align <- "center"

rwwc <- estim_RWWC(inputdata, Wname, J, W, Align=Align)
wavcor.output <- rwwc

DATES <- X2$Date
 
plot_estim_RWWC(inputdata, DATES=DATES, rwwc, Wname, J, W,
Align=Align, CEXAXIS=1.2)
```